# Insertar datos en un array dentro de un json

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Necesito almacenar datos en un array que esta dentro de un json, es decir que voy a tener varios usuarios que van a tener datos

```
let nombresUsuarios={
                datos:[{nombre :''},
                       {acierto:''},
                       {fallo  :''}]};
```

como llenarlo?

mi intento es:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        nombresUsuarios.datos.nombre=rows[i].nombre;
                        nombresUsuarios.datos.acierto=rows[i].dato1;
                        nombresUsuarios.datos.fallo=rows[i].dato2;
                    };
```

pero no llena nada, como lo hago?

Comment: datos es un vector , no crees que deberia ser algo como esto.
nombresUsuarios.datos[i].fallo=rows[i].dato2

Comment: @acR Lo que publicaste no es un JSON. Simplemente es un objeto. Pero, ¿en dónde está definida `rows`? Además, ¿es necesario que el array `nombresUsuarios.datos[]` tenga esa estructura? Parecería muy poco práctica y sería recomendable que la cambies. ¿Se puede modificar a algo más sencillo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para insertar los datos a un json utiliza el metodo [push](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp).

Deberia de funciona de la siguiente manera, prueba y cuentanos que tal te fue.

```html
var nombresUsuarios={datos:[{nombre :''},{acierto:''},{fallo:''}]};

var obj = JSON.parse(nombresUsuarios);

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
     obj['datos'].push({"nombre":rows[i].nombre,"acierto":rows[i].dato1,"fallo":rows[i].dato2});
};

nombresUsuarios= JSON.stringify(obj);
```